# Live reload no longer works after Angular 6 update

Tags: angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

The workaround is actually to delete the ClientApp/dist folder. But each time I "publish", I have to delete it again.

Do you know how to fix it?

My Startup.cs use this folder...

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a little more? Are you using the project template from `dotnet new angular` or what?

Comment: Yes, and I did update angular 5 to 6

Comment: Open http://localhost:5001 and then modify any HTML, live reload will not trigger. It appears that recompilation occurs, but the HTML is not updated in the browser.

Note: opening the Angular Live Development Server at http://localhost:53777 will live reload, but the backend does not work. That's why I believe this is a dotnet setup issue.

Comment: and this is why I don't use the dotnet template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `dotnet new angular` template

and Following this guide: https://update.angular.io/

and removing `--extract-css` from the `"scripts"` collection in `ClientApp/package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

I was able to successfully upgrade from angular 5 to 6, and the live reload features of both dotnet core, and the angular app were still functional.

---

As for getting YOUR project working, do you have the following code in your `Startup.cs` `Configure()` method?

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

This is how `dotnet` tells the angular cli which tells npm to start the live development server, which would be the first place I look if the live reload is not working.

The next place would be the `package.json` (which I pasted previously) should have `ng start` defined properly

If neither of these solve your problem, please let me know.

### Update

Error in the following sentence;

> The next place would be the `package.json` (which I pasted previously) should have `ng start` defined properly

Should read

> .. the `package.json` should have a `start` property defined in the `scripts` section, which will call `ng serve` with your appropriate command line arguments (if any)

Comment: It's called `ng serve` not `ng start`. ;) (unless you meant `npm start`)

Comment: Thanks, post did need updating, however neither `ng serve` or `ng start` are correct in the context of the post.  See update.